# Modificador de acesso propriedade C#

Tags: c#, .net, característica-linguagem, propriedade, private

Notei que é possível assinar o modo de acesso de uma propriedade como privado:

```
public string Codigo { get; private set; }
```

Ou simplesmente ignorá-la:

```
public string Codigo { get; }
```

Existe alguma diferença ou algum cenário onde deve ser utilizado uma dessas assinaturas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A primeira forma:

```
public string Codigo { get; private set; }
```

declara uma propriedade de leitura pública e escrita privada.

A segunda forma:

```
public string Codigo { get; }
```

declara uma propriedade *readonly* pública, como é *readonly* apenas é possível iniciá-la no construtor ou durante a declaração.

A segunda forma garante imutabilidade externa e interna, a primeira apenas garante imutabilidade externa.