# Propriedade com set privado

Tags: c#, propriedade, private

Existe diferença entre declarar o set privado ou simplesmente omiti-lo?

```
public int UmaPropriedade {get; private set;}
public int OutraPropriedade {get;}
```

As duas linhas de código são equivalentes?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Modificador de acesso propriedade C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/122573/modificador-de-acesso-propriedade-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não são equivalentes, nessa linha:

```
public int UmaPropriedade {get; private set;}
```

O valor da propriedade `UmaPropriedade` só poderá ser alterada pela própria classe, nem as classes filhas poderão setar essa propriedade.

Já nesta linha:

```
public int OutraPropriedade {get;}
```

Não existe o método `set`, então ninguém poderá setar alguma coisa nessa propriedade.

Comment: *"(...) ninguém poderá setar alguma coisa nessa propriedade (...)"*?

Answer (score 4):

Vejamos como este código é gerado:

```
.class private auto ansi '<Module>'
{
} // end of class <Module>

.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit C
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    // Fields
    .field private int32 '<UmaPropriedade>k__BackingField'
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
        01 00 00 00
    )
    .field private initonly int32 '<OutraPropriedade>k__BackingField'
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
        01 00 00 00
    )

    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig specialname 
        instance int32 get_UmaPropriedade () cil managed 
    {
        .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
            01 00 00 00
        )
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
        // Code size 7 (0x7)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: ldfld int32 C::'<UmaPropriedade>k__BackingField'
        IL_0006: ret
    } // end of method C::get_UmaPropriedade

    .method private hidebysig specialname 
        instance void set_UmaPropriedade (
            int32 'value'
        ) cil managed 
    {
        .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
            01 00 00 00
        )
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2058
        // Code size 8 (0x8)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: ldarg.1
        IL_0002: stfld int32 C::'<UmaPropriedade>k__BackingField'
        IL_0007: ret
    } // end of method C::set_UmaPropriedade

    .method public hidebysig specialname 
        instance int32 get_OutraPropriedade () cil managed 
    {
        .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
            01 00 00 00
        )
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2061
        // Code size 7 (0x7)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: ldfld int32 C::'<OutraPropriedade>k__BackingField'
        IL_0006: ret
    } // end of method C::get_OutraPropriedade

    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2069
        // Code size 7 (0x7)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        IL_0006: ret
    } // end of method C::.ctor

    // Properties
    .property instance int32 UmaPropriedade()
    {
        .get instance int32 C::get_UmaPropriedade()
        .set instance void C::set_UmaPropriedade(int32)
    }
    .property instance int32 OutraPropriedade()
    {
        .get instance int32 C::get_OutraPropriedade()
    }

} // end of class C
```

Veja [no **SharpLab**](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgDAAhgRgNwFgBQMDMSBMCAwggN5YKVJ5gB2wCAqgLYCGACgE4D2ADp2ACmAE1bDBZAOaDgqBPzAA3VsAkBnGagC+WAJC4EdBgHkArsE4ceCkWImlpsnZi1A==).

Ambas permitem que publicamente pegue o valor, mas há uma importante diferença, o primeiro permite que a classe altere seu valor, mas não publicamente, o segundo não permite que o valor seja alterado de forma alguma, efetivamente ele é somente leitura, portanto, ou deve usar um inicializador ou deve inicializar no construtor, caso contrário não faz sentido ter uma propriedade assim. Não que a primeira forma faça sentido, na maioria dos casos, sem uma inicialização.